# PHP handle $_POST from XMLHttpRequest2 with new FormData() and append()

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest-level2

**Using PHP how can I process data sent via `XMLHttpRequest2` with `new FormData()` and `append()` like traditional form data?**

In my AJAX parameters handling function the parameters would look like the following:

```
q1=v1&q2=v2&q3=v3
```

You could use `print_r($_POST);` and determine to access `$_POST['q1']` to get the value `v1` easily.

---

While testing `XMLHttpRequest2` with `new FormData()` and `append()` on the server when I have PHP and use `print_r($_POST);` I get the following:

```
-----------------------------3875113001076
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="q1"
v1

-----------------------------3875113001076
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="q2"
v2

-----------------------------3875113001076
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="q3"
v3
```

However I can no longer access `$_POST['q1'];`.

---

**JavaScript AJAX Parameters Function**

```
function ajax_parameters(id)
{
 var f;
 var fd = new FormData();

 if (id_(id) || typeof id=='object' && id.nodeName.toLowerCase()=='form')
 {
  if (id_(id)) {f = id_(id);}
  else {f = id;}

  for (var i = 0;i<f.elements.length;i++)
  {
   if (f.elements[i].type!='file')
   {
    fd.append(f.elements[i].name,f.elements[i].value);
   }
   else
   {
    for (var j = 0; j < f.elements[i].files.length; ++j)
    {
     fd.append(f.elements[i].name+'['+j+']', f.elements[i].files[j],f.elements[i].files.item(j).name);
    }
   }
  }
 }
 return fd;
}
```

Comment: Weird, I just tested AJAX with `print_r ($_POST)` and could retrieve the result just fine. Maybe post the full code you're using?

Comment: @GGG Updated, adding `encodeURIComponent()` doesn't seem to do any good.

Comment: You're able to use `new FormData(id)` to create the FormData if the `id` is the form element. No need to iterate through all elements of the form since FormData can do that by itself.

Comment: @GGG Okay, working on it...

Comment: Also, you'll need to iterate through the files as FormData doesn't does that.

Comment: I wrote a minimal test case and it worked. Removing `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` from the main `AJAX` function resolved the issue which is odd since I was certain it was required when you have file uploads in XMLHttpRequest2 but whatever. Please post your second comment as an answer and I'll gladly accept and comment how it worked for me for others to benefit from. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're able to use `new FormData(id)` to create the FormData if the id is the form element. No need to iterate through all elements of the form since FormData can do that by itself.

Comment: Firefox 38 ESR apparently automatically determines the correct mime (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded ` or `multipart/form-data`) but I'll need to test. Visit my profile/site to see what you're contributing to and thanks!